# Deployed Isolated Function App returns 404

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-bicep

After I've deployed my (Isolated V7) Azure Function App using Azure Devops (combination of YAML and Bicep), I can not seem to access my HTTPTrigger; a 404 is returned.

Here is my C# HttpTrigger, a basic GET without authentication:

```cs
        [Function(nameof(StartImport))]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> StartImport(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            // call orchestrator...
        }
```

Locally, this all runs fine and I get a 200 OK response when fetching `http://localhost:7222/api/StartImport` using Postman.

This is the YAML for building the project:

```yaml
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        inputs:
          packageType: "sdk"
          version: "7.x"
  
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: "restore"
          projects: "**/[PROJECT].csproj"
  
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          projects: "**/[PROJECT].csproj"
          arguments: "--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)"
  
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: publish
          publishWebProjects: false
          projects: "**/[PROJECT].csproj"
          arguments: "--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output publish_output"
          modifyOutputPath: false
  
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output"
          includeRootFolder: false
          archiveFile: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
          
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: "Publish build artifacts"
```

Then a Bicep file is run to deploy the infrastructure.
It creates a Function App with a Premium (EP1) plan and a storage account.
Here is part of the Bicep file that creates the plan and corresponding site:

```bicep
resource plan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'pl-${functionAppName}'
  location: resourceLocation
  sku: {
    tier: 'ElasticPremium'
    name: 'EP1'
  }
  kind: 'elastic'
  properties: {
    targetWorkerCount: 0
    maximumElasticWorkerCount: 20
    elasticScaleEnabled: true
    isSpot: false
  }
}

resource functionappsite 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: '${functionAppName}'
  location: resourceLocation
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'dotnet-isolated'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
          value: '1'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: '[CONNECTION]'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: '[CONNECTION]'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: '[SHARE NAME]'
        }       
        {
          name: 'AzureBlobConnectionString'
          value: '[CONNECTION]'
        }
      ]
      use32BitWorkerProcess: true
    }
    serverFarmId: plan.id
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
  }
}
```

And then finally, the ZIP is deployed:

```yaml
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: [SUBSCRIPTION]
              appName: ${{ parameters.functionAppName }}
              package: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/drop/build$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

I can see that the ZIP file is deployed to my function app; it is placed inside 'C:\home\data\SitePackages'.

I cannot see any functions in the Function App 'Functions' blade but that seems to be expected:

[image]

It looks like the storage account was also successfully instantiated for the function app:

[image]

When I try to access my trigger however, by sending a GET request to `https://[FUNCTIONAPPNAME].azurewebsites.net/api/StartImport` or to `https://[FUNCTIONAPPNAME].azurewebsites.net/StartImport`, a 404 is returned.
The site itself (`https://[FUNCTIONAPPNAME].azurewebsites.net/`) does show a confirmation screen that my app is up&running...

How can I access my trigger? How can I check deployment was successful and my trigger is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the fact that my publish output was zipped twice. Everything was deployed successfully, but the final output in `wwwroot` was just empty, causing a 404.

Fixed this by removing the `ArchiveFiles@2` task and slightly modifying the used paths:

```yaml
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        inputs:
          packageType: "sdk"
          version: "7.x"
  
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: "restore"
          projects: "**/[PROJECT].csproj"
  
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          projects: "**/[PROJECT].csproj"
          arguments: "--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)"
  
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: publish
          publishWebProjects: false
          projects: "**/[PROJECT].csproj"
          arguments: "--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-build --output publish_output"
          modifyOutputPath: false
            
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: "Publish build artifacts"
          PathtoPublish: 'publish_output'
          ArtifactName: 'drop'
          publishLocation: 'Container'
```